# ListBuckets operation: Access Denied when use list_buckets()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've read the related posts but can't fix it.

I use boto3 to call s3 api list_buckets() (image below), but I receive "*An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied*"

I have set IAM Policy below (I have only one user below)

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucket*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In *buckettestcothexoa* bucket I was set policy below:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1546414473940",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1546414471931",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::0646251919XX:user/user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buckettestcothexoa"
        }
    ]
}
```

Get client function (I have checked `get_caller_identity()` and it returned true user)

```
def get_client():
    return boto3.client('s3',  aws_access_key_id=os.environ["MYBOARD_AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
            aws_secret_access_key=os.environ["MYBOARD_AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])
```

When I use another api it working normal, only get list bucket show this error, thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SterQ.png)

Comment: Most likely you are using different user that you think you are using, or there are other permissions denying the access.

Comment: Do a `boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()`. Check the output to see if it matches the user that you are expecting.

Comment: @jellycsc @Marcin Hi I run `boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()`, and the result returned is the current User I used same above (`arn:aws:iam::0646251919XX:user/user`). I don't know if there is something wrong with my installation?

Comment: Hi, I have found the reason why the API call is failing, because in my account I have assigned an additional permission package, which has the permission `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` in `DENY` state, and this package has the highest privileges the highest priority, so even if you add full permissions, it can't be done. Thanks, everyone for your help.